# spring security : Why can't we access Hibernate entitiy parameters in @PreAuthorize?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security, spring-3, spelevaluationexception

I have the following interface method on which I am applying `@PreAuthoriz`e :

```
@PreAuthorize("doSomething(#user.id)")
void something(User user, List<User> accessList);
```

where `User` is a **Hibernate entity** object. It gives me an error :

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1007E:(pos 13): Field or property 'id' cannot be found on null  at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:204)

There is no way that the `user` parameter is null, as if I remove the annotation, and inspect the value of user in the method that implements this interface method, there is a valid `User` object present there. Additionally, just before calling this method, I have made sure that the user object is correctly constructed.

I really can't figure out why would the `user` field be considered null by the SPEL parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with the debugger what's going on in *MethodSecurityEvaluationContext*, inside *Object lookupVariable(String name)* method:

```
    @Override
    public Object lookupVariable(String name) {
    Object variable = super.lookupVariable(name);

    if (variable != null) {
        return variable;
    }

    if (!argumentsAdded) {
        addArgumentsAsVariables();
        argumentsAdded = true;
    }
```

and so you can see what's really going on in the *addArgumentsAsVariables()* method as the convertion of method arguments to SPEL variables is implemented very clearly in Spring.

Comment: Thanks for that.. As it turned out, the variable name in my method argument in the interface declaration was different than the name in my actual implementation of the method... Spring was looking for the latter name

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security has a better answer for this problem now:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize

Basically, you can use the @P annotation or @Param annotation if you are using < JDK 8.

Comment: Thanks, adding a `@Param` annotation to the method signature worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `LazyParamAwareEvaluationContext`,inside `loadArgsAsVariables()` method, version 3.1.0.

The same key for different Entity, because of implementing interface.

Answer (score 0):

I need to add something to this as the title indicates that we cannot access hibernate properties.

There are two editions of hasPermission, the loaded object and the serialized object. Here is some code from a test case:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#organization, 'edit')")
public long protectedMethod(Organization organization)
{
    return organization.getId();
}
```

And for the latter here we see that we can infact access the id proprty of the organization (which is a hibernate entity):

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#organization.getId(), 'organization', 'edit')")
public long protectedMethodSerializableEdtion(Organization organization)
{
    return organization.getId();
}
```