# targetDomainObject is always null in PermissionEvaluator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-el

I have a CRUD repository from [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security) of Spring Data. I'm trying to add custom permission evaluation, but in my implementation of `PermissionEvalutor`, `targetDomainObject` is always `null`.

**ItemRepository**

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {
  @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#entity, 'DELETE')")
  <S extends Item> S save(S entity);

  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
  void delete(Long id);
}
```

Following the suggestions in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317293/custom-permissions-in-spring-security-targetid-null) of making the interface and implementation parameter names to match, I've tried changing `entity` by `item` in both the expression and the method parameter. I'm not sure what implementation should match against what interface here, so I'm guessing is `SimpleJpaRepository` against `ItemRepository`/`CrudRepository`. Anyway, it doesn't work, `targetDomainObject` is always null. Same for `targetId` in the other method.

Debugging `MethodSecurityEvaluationContext.lookupVariable` shows that `args.length = 0`, inside the method `addArgumentsAsVariables()`, that then logs `Unable to resolve method parameter names for method: public abstract xx.xxx.Item xx.xxx.ItemRepository.save(xx.xxx.Item). Debug symbol information is required if you are using parameter names in expressions.`. At `lookupVariable`, everything is null.

Is the debug symbol not `#`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what did you find when following the suggestion in the referenced question accepted answer? "You can also check how `MethodSecurityEvaluationContext.lookupVariable` method is working with the debugger."

Comment: @JensSchauder Edited question with debug info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't looked in the actual code, but judging from what you write about the debug information, Spring isn't able to find the parameter names, probably since the come from interfaces and those aren't included in the bytecode by default.

Try adding a `-parameters` compiler flag. Also see this answer for a probably similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40787280

Comment: That was it. Thanks, I was going crazy